# $\iint (x+y) dx dy $ What is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

**Question**

Solve the indefinite integral: $\iint (x+y) dx dy $

**Attempt**

When calculating this indefinite double integral, I would first start with x and then y such that my solution would be:

- $\frac{1}2x^2 y + \frac{1}2y^2 x + c_1y + c_2$

But Wolfram Alpha's Solution is:

- $\frac{1}2x^2 y + \frac{1}2y^2 x + c_1x + c_2$

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is really no such thing as indefinite multiple integrals. Both answers are technically wrong in the strictest sense, because if one integrates with respect to $x$ first, the constant $c$ is really an arbitrary function of $y$, $c(y)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, maybe you need to say more on your attempts so that people may be able to help you! :)

Comment: When evaluating single indefinite integrals there is always a constant. My attempt was simply to integrate it first for x and then for y. As when integrating for x there will be a constant after integrating for y this constant imo should become to c*y

Comment: @NinadMunshi could you please give more information what you mean with $y,c(y)$ i don’t unterstand the notation

Comment: The order of integration matters for "indefinite" multiple integrals.   [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=double+integral+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22x%2By%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1%22%7D+-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22) lets you pick the order, and you can see that toggling between the two gives your two results.

Comment: @lulu I have noticed that already. But what was my mistake when I take the order as dxdy

Comment: There is no mistake, it's just notation.  WA puts the first integration variable last, you put it first.  Since people don't usually write down indefinite multiple integrals (it being unclear what such a thing ought to mean) I'm not sure if there is a standard convention for the notation.

Comment: You are wrong in stating that the integral when $x$ is constant should just be $cy$.  The function $e^{y\sin(y)}$ also has derivative $0$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Maths11235813 it's not notation, it's grammar such as "Lulu, meet my student, Maths11235813." When integrating multivariable functions, the constant is a function of all of the other variables not integrated, it is not necessarily a true constant. In this case, "all of the other variables" is just $y$.

Comment: Anyway the point is, there is no such thing as indefinite multiple integrals. Such quantities are ill defined and serve no purpose in a fundamental theorem of calculus sort of way.

Comment: Even if you think there is such a thing as double indefinite integral, most people don't; so when you ask about it include a link that explains what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one dimension, if the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ is $F(x)+c$, this means that when you differentiate $F(x)+c$ you get back to $f(x)$. $F(x)+c$ really denotes a family of functions, the *antiderivatives* of $f$, which differ from each other only by a constant; when you differentiate any of these antiderivatives, the $c$ disappears, so you always get $f$ as a result.

If we extend this to two dimensions, we find that the antiderivatives of $f(x,y)$ take the form $F(x,y)+c_1(x)+c_2(y)$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary functions of one variable. This is because when we differentiate this with respect to $x$ and $y$, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}(F(x,y)+c_1(x)+c_2(y))$, the functions $c_1$ and $c_2$ disappear in either the first or the second stage, so the result is independent of the functions $c_1$ and $c_2$. (I am ignoring complications that arise when the order of differentiation matters; this won't happen as long as the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous.)

Your answer differs from Wolfram Alpha's answer by a function of the form $ax+by+c$; and because this function can be expressed as the sum of a function only of $x$ and a function only of $y$, they are equally valid antiderivatives of the function $f(x,y)=x+y$.

But a more complete answer would be $\frac12 x^2y+\frac12 y^2x + c_1(x)+c_2(y)$.

Comment: I think to show that they are equally valid antiderivatives one might also use the theorem of Fubini